# Reference Request : The number of binary string with some special condition (open problem)

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, binary, open-problem

(Sorry for my poor english...)

I wonder the reference of Simon Marais Mathematics competition 2019 problem B4. This problem is as follow.

(They said this problem is open problem.)

B4. A set $\mathcal{B}$ of binary strings is defined following rules.

1. 1 in $\mathcal{B}$.
2. If $s_1s_2\dots s_n$ in $\mathcal{B}$ and $n$ is odd, then $s_1s_2\dots s_n 0$ and $0s_1s_2\dots s_n$ are in $\mathcal{B}$.
3. If $s_1s_2\dots s_n$ in $\mathcal{B}$ and $n$ is even, then $s_1s_2\dots s_n 1$ and $1s_1s_2\dots s_n$ are in $\mathcal{B}$.

Let $b_n$ be the number of strings in $\mathcal{B}$ with length $n$.

Then, determine $\liminf_{n\to \infty} (b_n)^{1/n}$ and $\limsup_{n\to \infty} (b_n)^{1/n}$.

I want to find the reference of this problem...

Is there any reference related to this problem?

Here are [the problem statement](https://www.simonmarais.org/uploads/8/2/3/5/82358688/smmc-2019-paper-b.pdf) and [the solution to part $(a)$ of the problem](https://www.simonmarais.org/uploads/8/2/3/5/82358688/smmc-2019-solutions.pdf), which asks to show that there exist constants $c_1,c_2\gt0$ and $1.6\lt\lambda_1,\lambda_2\lt1.9$ such that $ c_1\lambda_1^n\lt b_n\lt c_2λ_2^n$ for all positive integers $n$.

Comment: Did you compute the first few and try oeis?

Comment: @Mason. Yes. I computed the first few term, 1,2,3,5,9,16 and I couldn't find in oeis.

Comment: [Here's Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/8f59c7e7f2d43dcc1bc0dc8080c2a154) to compute the initial values of $b_n$. For $n=1,\ldots,30$ they are $1,2,3,5,9,16,29,52,94,170,308,560,1018,1856,3383,6177,11279,20614,37685,68926,126112,$ $230802,422557,773730,1417222,2596086,4756834,8716434,15975357,29280686$. This sequence is not in OEIS. $\sqrt[30]{b_{30}}\approx1.7737$, but this value is far from converged. It seems possible that the limit is $2$.

Comment: @joriki The limit is not 2. Simon marias 2019 problem B4.(a) is that there exists constants $c_1, c_2$ and $1.6<\lambda_1, \lambda_2<1.9$ such that $c_1\lambda_1^n<b_n<c_2\lambda_2^n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Interesting. Could you link to that? Two more values: $b_{31}=53675927$ and $b_{32}=98400412$, with $\sqrt[32]{b_{32}}\approx1.7774$.

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please include all relevant knowledge that you already have. Please refer to [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959) in the FAQ.

Comment: @joriki I wiil do that. Thank you for your kind advice!